# Python regex expression to match pattern in sentences

Tags: python, regex

Given the paragraph for example

.This is figure 3a. This is fig 4a . I like (figure 5).  This is important (fig 6a).

I will like a python regex to extract the sentences based on figure number. I am trying

1. This is figure 3a using ([^.]*?fig.*3[^.]*.)
2. This fig 4a  ([^.]*?fig.*4[^.]*.)
3. I like (figure 5)  ([^.]*?fig.*5[^.]*.)
4. This is important (fig 6a)  ([^.]*?fig.*6[^.]*.)

but the matching is not specific. Number 4 for example will extract all figures. I just one specific figures based on the figure number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace,

- `.*` before `4` with `[^.]*`
- replace `4` with `\d`

Code:

```
In[3]: s = "This is figure 3a. This is fig 4a . I like (figure 5). This is important (fig 6a)."
In[4]: import re
In[5]: re.findall(r'[^.]*?fig[^.]*\d[^.]*', s)
Out[5]: 
['This is figure 3a',
 ' This is fig 4a ',
 ' I like (figure 5)',
 ' This is important (fig 6a)']
```

or

```
In[8]: re.findall(r'\s*([^.]*?fig[^.]*\d[^.]*?)(?=\s*\.)', s)
Out[8]: 
['This is figure 3a',
 'This is fig 4a',
 'I like (figure 5)',
 'This is important (fig 6a)']
```

Comment: I missed out important information about my question. Please see edits.

Comment: then replace `\d` with the num you want.

Comment: what if a sentence is of the form "This is fig. 3a which is of interest. " How do I handle the dot after fig

Comment: just change `fig` in the above to `fig\.?`